# Запуск python скрипта из другого скрипта без остановки

Tags: python

Мне нужно запускать скрипт 2 из скрипта 1, так, чтобы скрипт 1 на время работы скрипта 1 не останавливался. В настоящие время он ждет выполнения скрипта 2. Помогите пожалуйста

Скрипт(1) rjrg

```py
import fhrrd
import bank
import time

def mine():
    fhrrd.mine()

def g():
    print("g")
```

Скрипт(2) fhrrd

```py
import time
import bank
def mine():
    for i in range(60):
        bank.a +=1
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

Всё, решение нашел. Помог threading.Thread

Comment: Ищите в сторону многопоточности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста :)

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def script1():
    for i in range(50, 100):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(i)


def script2():
    thread1 = Thread(target=script1)
    thread1.start()
    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(i)

script2()
```

В этом коде, мы запускаем script2, он запускает script1 и работает сам, не ожидая окончания работы script1.

Если все-таки появится необходимость ждать, это легко реализовать, добавив строку "thread1.join()", сразу после строки "thread1.start()".

Comment: Спасибо именно такой ответ я и нашел в сети) Спасибо вам за помощь